# DynamicDataDisplay chart with custom datetime labels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, dynamic-data-display

Im writing application with charts. One of this chart has horizontal DateTime axis and i have problem with showing proper labels.

For now my X axis contains about 3 days, and the labels looks terrible.

It shows only days counter at axis and the bottom label is whole month.

I would like to make that bottom label will be days and at the axis values every f.e. 6hours.

How can i do that?

Comment: What control are you using?

Comment: ChartPlotter for plotting and LineGraph as a child graph. And of course HorizontalDateTimeAxis as horizontal axis

Comment: You're using Dynamic Display Library, then?

Comment: Yes, its in the topic :) and tags